# What causes repeat trip of thermostat in dryer?

Tags: heating, dryer

My dryer did not produce heat. After some online research, there was a solution that included pressing a small red reset button. I did this and the dryer worked for a while, but then the heat stopped. I repeated the “repair”, but the dryer stopped producing heat again after a while. What would be my next step. I’m not technical, but hoping there could be something that wont need a specialist for repair.

Comment: 90% of the time... partially or completely clogged exhaust ducting.

Comment: Isherwood that should be an answer. I have found lint and sand blocking the air flow in the past the thermal protector is doing its job so the cause needs to be identified. I agree that it is usually a plugged vent.+

Comment: You could have a problem with the blower fan in the dryer.  Does it make a lot of noise when running?  I had a dryer where the drum fan had a "D" shaped hole for the rod that spun it.  Eventually the hole would wear out to a circle and the rod would spin but not turn the fan much, leading to the dryer shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause of your dryer over heating is caused by a blockage of air flow in the dryer exhaust venting. This has happened to me and causes the dryer to display a flashing AF (air flow) indicator.

Blockage is generally caused by build up of lint in the venting duct. It can also be due to something closing off the outside end of the vending duct such as snow buildup or or the vent flapper door getting stuck shut.

In my case there is about 22 feet of 4" ducting that unfortunately has to route through seven separate right angle joints as the duct goes up through an inside wall to between floor joints between 1st and 2nd floor before it finally makes it way through the back garage wall to the exterior. Even though the dryer has a good lint screen that is cleaned regularly some lint makes its way out with the warm damp air into the duct. The long duct cools the air and allows a good share of the lint to end up sticking to the inside of the pipe. Eventually over time the duct work needs to be opened up and cleaned....a painful and lengthy job.